# Passing va_list as function argument

Tags: vala

I've created a simple SO example demonstrating various ways to pass va_list as function arg. The problem I'm trying to solve is passing the va_list in a callback from a shared object to the main module.

```
/*libcode.vala shared library (libvala-0.38)*/
namespace SOTestLib {
    public const string TESTSTR = "my test string";
    public const string EXPECTFORMATSTR = "expect test:%s";
    public const string EXPECTFORMATSTR_VA_ARG0 = "1==1";
    public delegate bool delegatefnExpect (bool expression, string format, va_list valist);
    public delegatefnExpect delfnExpect;
    public delegate bool delegatefnString (string mystring);
    public delegatefnString delfnString;

    public string gTestStr;
    public string gExpectResultStr;

    private void show_string(string mystring) {
        stdout.printf("show_string mystring[%s] gTestStr[%s]\n", mystring, gTestStr);
        assert (mystring == gTestStr);
        assert (delfnString != null);
        delfnString(mystring);
        }

    private bool expect(bool expression, string sformat, ...) {
        assert (delfnExpect != null);
        assert (sformat == EXPECTFORMATSTR);

        va_list _valist = va_list ();
        gExpectResultStr = sformat.vprintf (_valist);
        stdout.printf("expect[%s]\n", gExpectResultStr);
        return delfnExpect(expression, sformat , _valist);
        }

    private void my_printf (string format, ...) {
        va_list va_list = va_list ();
        string res = format.vprintf (va_list);
        stdout.puts (res);
        }
    public int run_demo() {
        //REFER:https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/string.vprintf.html
        // Output: ``Shut up, K-9!``
        my_printf ("Shut %s, %c-%d!\n", "up", 'K', 9);

        gTestStr = TESTSTR;
        show_string(TESTSTR);
        expect(1 == 1, EXPECTFORMATSTR, EXPECTFORMATSTR_VA_ARG0);
        return 0;
        }
    }
/*main.vala linked with libcode.so shared library (libvala-0.38)*/
using SOTestLib;
public bool cbfnString(string test_str) {
    stdout.printf("cbfnString test_str[%s] gTestStr[%s]\n", test_str, gTestStr);
    assert (test_str == gTestStr);
    return true;
    }
public bool cbfnExpect(bool expression, string format, va_list args) {
    stdout.printf("cbfnExpect format[%s] format.length[%d]\n",
                  format, format.length);
    assert (format == EXPECTFORMATSTR);
    string res = format.vprintf(args);
    assert (res != null);
    stdout.printf("cbfnExpect res[%s] gExpectResultStr[%s]\n", res, gExpectResultStr);
    assert(res == gExpectResultStr);
    return expression;
    }
static int main(string[] args) {
    delfnString = (delegatefnString)cbfnString;
    delfnExpect = (delegatefnExpect)cbfnExpect;

    return run_demo();
    }
```

Here is the result of running the test...

```
===========================================================================
---Run main --
===========================================================================
./stackoverflow/libcallback_strings/lib/libcallback_strings.exe
Shut up, K-9!
show_string mystring[my test string] gTestStr[my test string]
cbfnString test_str[my test string] gTestStr[my test string]
expect[expect test:1==1]
cbfnExpect format[expect test:%s] format.length[14]
cbfnExpect res[expect test:(null)] gExpectResultStr[expect test:1==1]
**
ERROR:/media/george/SharedData/Projects/Vala/LanguageServer/stackoverflow/libcallback_strings/main.vala:15:cbfnExpect: assertion failed: (res == gExpectResultStr)
stackoverflow/so_examples.mk:252: recipe for target 'libcallback_strings' failed
make: *** [libcallback_strings] Aborted
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 2
```

For some reason in cbfnExpect, va_list args is no longer valid.  It seems as if va_list address (or addresses within the struct)  is only valid within the shared library. Is this not the correct/allowed usage of va_list?

Answer (score 0):

In `private bool expect`, if I comment out setting `gExpectResultStr` as follows:

`//gExpectResultStr = sformat.vprintf (_valist);`

Then, in the first line of the `static int main` method, I added:

`gExpectResultStr = "expect test:1==1";`

The test passes. Since `gExpectResultStr` is the same every time the program is run, I just statically set it to the correct value when the program starts. *Removing* the call to `vprintf` in `expect` seems to be what fixes it.

My guess is that calling `sformat.vprintf` on the va_list, under the hood, in the C implementation, invalidates the `va_list`.

When diffing the generated C code for both the passing and failing code, here is what I came up with. Staring at the code for a while, the only potential part that might mess up the va_list is the call to `g_strdup_vprintf()`. I guess that function frees the va_list?

```
$ diff -Naur libcode-pass.c libcode-fails.c
--- libcode-pass.c  2018-01-20 09:19:24.455838766 -0800
+++ libcode-fails.c 2018-01-20 09:19:59.631260461 -0800
@@ -66,26 +66,32 @@
    SOTestLibdelegatefnExpect _tmp0_;
    const gchar* _tmp1_;
    va_list _valist = {0};
-   FILE* _tmp2_;
-   const gchar* _tmp3_;
-   SOTestLibdelegatefnExpect _tmp4_;
-   gboolean _tmp5_;
-   const gchar* _tmp6_;
+   const gchar* _tmp2_;
+   gchar* _tmp3_;
+   FILE* _tmp4_;
+   const gchar* _tmp5_;
+   SOTestLibdelegatefnExpect _tmp6_;
    gboolean _tmp7_;
+   const gchar* _tmp8_;
+   gboolean _tmp9_;
    g_return_val_if_fail (sformat != NULL, FALSE);
    _tmp0_ = so_test_lib_delfnExpect;
    _vala_assert (_tmp0_ != NULL, "delfnExpect != null");
    _tmp1_ = sformat;
    _vala_assert (g_strcmp0 (_tmp1_, SO_TEST_LIB_EXPECTFORMATSTR) == 0, "sformat == EXPECTFORMATSTR");
    va_start (_valist, sformat);
-   _tmp2_ = stdout;
-   _tmp3_ = so_test_lib_gExpectResultStr;
-   fprintf (_tmp2_, "expect[%s]\n", _tmp3_);
-   _tmp4_ = so_test_lib_delfnExpect;
-   _tmp5_ = expression;
-   _tmp6_ = sformat;
-   _tmp7_ = _tmp4_ (_tmp5_, _tmp6_, _valist);
-   result = _tmp7_;
+   _tmp2_ = sformat;
+   _tmp3_ = g_strdup_vprintf (_tmp2_, _valist);
+   _g_free0 (so_test_lib_gExpectResultStr);
+   so_test_lib_gExpectResultStr = _tmp3_;
+   _tmp4_ = stdout;
+   _tmp5_ = so_test_lib_gExpectResultStr;
+   fprintf (_tmp4_, "expect[%s]\n", _tmp5_);
+   _tmp6_ = so_test_lib_delfnExpect;
+   _tmp7_ = expression;
+   _tmp8_ = sformat;
+   _tmp9_ = _tmp6_ (_tmp7_, _tmp8_, _valist);
+   result = _tmp9_;
    va_end (_valist);
    return result;
 }
```